# Sql server database synchronization on 2 different server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-data-sync

I need advice on setting up synchronization between 2 SQL Server 2016 databases on standalone servers in different sites. What techniques should I best use and how should I go about setting up synchronization?

Currently I have a SQL Server at one site and a second server at a different site.

The requirement is to have database replication from the first site to the second site only.

Comment: Please describe why you need it because there are multiple solution available. There is not enough information to advice you.

Answer (score 3):

You can go in three ways:

1. Use replication. This is a large area of ​​database engineering. I recommend you get started with [types of replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/types-of-replication?view=sql-server-ver15).
2. Use [log shipping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/log-shipping/about-log-shipping-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15). This is usually used to create an emergency database (hot backup). Pay attention: The secondary server will read-only.
3. The easiest option. Run [backup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on the primary server and [restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) this file on the secondary server. it is a good idea If the restore procedure takes a little time. There are paid cloud services like [SqlBak](https://sqlbak.com/) and [IBM Cloud Backup](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/backup) that will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

well, in general, without knowing the details of your needs, you can use [SQL SERVER log shipping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/log-shipping/about-log-shipping-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

not the best method in my opinion but it sounds like something that will suit your needs

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can i know what are other methods available. My requiremebt is simple , the datsbase in site A should be mirrored to 2nd site B.

Comment: well, when using the log shipping, you are getting a snapshot of the DB, it is more of a constant backed-up DB instead of a replica.
when saying Replica, you usually want a replication that is updated in an interval of time, let's say, DB B is 5 minutes late than DB A, and that indeed is a replica.

if time is not a factor, log shipping should be fine